# Impala Query: Find value in pipe-separated list

Tags: sql, regex, impala

I have a column containing rows of pipe separated STRING values:

```
|   colA    |
 ___________
| 5|4|2|255 |
| 5|4|4|0   |
| 5|4|4|3   |
| 5|4|4|4   |
```

I need to create a query that will select all rows that contain 4 or 5, but never 2 or 3. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT t.colA
FROM my_table t
WHERE (t IN ("4", "5") AND t NOT IN ("2","3")
```

Resulting in:

```
|   colA    |
 ___________
| 5|4|4|0   |
| 5|4|4|4   |
```

I ended up using a combination of the two answers below, as using either method alone still left me with rows containing only "255". Here's the final query:

```
SELECT t.colA
FROM my_table t
WHERE (t.colA IN ('4', '5') OR t.colA LIKE "%|5|%" 
       OR t.colA LIKE "%|5" OR t.colA LIKE "5|%")
AND t.colA NOT LIKE "%3%"    
AND t.colA NOT LIKE "%|2|%" 
AND t.colA NOT REGEXP "^2|%" 
AND t.colA NOT REGEXP "%|2$"
```

There is probably a more elegant way to do this, but that does the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the [`LIKE`](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/v2-0-x/topics/impala_operators.html#like_unique_1) function ?

```
where (t like  '%4%' or t like  '%5%')
and (t not like  '%2%' and t not like  '%3%')
```

That should do the job.

Comment: Oh wow, so simple I can't believe I didn't think of it. Thanks so much; works like a charm.