# Impala regex to find "2", but not "255", in pipe-delimited list

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, impala

I [originally asked for help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173825/impala-query-find-value-in-pipe-separated-list) finding values in a pipe-delimited list where the values must include `4` or `5`, but never `2` or `3`. However, the accepted solution returns the value `255` by itself.

I have a data set with pipe delimited values that can be either `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4` 0r `255`, such as this:

```
|    colA    |
 ____________
| 1|1|0|255  |
| 5|4|4|2    |
| 5|4|4|3    |
| 5|4|4|4    |
| 1|0|0|0    |
| 0|2|0|1|2  |
| 5|5|0|5    |
| 0|5        |
| 5|5|255|255|
| 0|3|1|2|3  |
| 5|5|5|2|3|3|
| 0|2|0|0|0|2|
| 5|255|1|1|5|
| 4|255|4    |
| 2|2|3      |
| 255|0      |
| 5          |
| 5|5|1      |
```

I need a query that will return rows that include a value of `4` or `5`, but never `2` or `3`.

```
|    colA    |
 ____________
| 5|4|4|3    |   
| 5|4|4|4    |
| 5|5|0|5    |
| 0|5        |
| 5|5|255|255|
| 5|255|1|1|5|
| 4|255|4    |
| 5          |
| 5|5|1      |
```

The closest I've come is this query:

```
SELECT clin.clin_sig 
FROM clinvar clin
WHERE (clin_sig NOT REGEXP '3|2[^5]'
AND clin_sig REGEXP '4|[^25]5')
```

But it's  missing the following entries, so something is wonky:

- `5`
- `5|255`
- `5|5|5|5|5|5|5`
- `5|0`
- `5|255|255`
- `5|5|1`

I've also tried this, but it's very slow and still missing a few results:

```
WHERE (clin.clin_sig LIKE "%4%" OR clin.clin_sig REGEXP "^5$"  
  OR clin.clin_sig REGEXP "^5\\|" 
  OR clin.clin_sig REGEXP "\\|5$" OR clin.clin_sig REGEXP "\\|5\\|")
AND clin.clin_sig NOT REGEXP "^2$" 
AND clin.clin_sig NOT REGEXP "\\|2$"
AND clin.clin_sig NOT REGEXP "^2\\|"
AND clin.clin_sig NOT LIKE "%3%"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    clin_sig     REGEXP '^[[:<:]](4|5)[[:>:]]$'
AND clin_sig NOT REGEXP '^[[:<:]](2|3)[[:>:]]$'
```

Please provide more test cases.

Comment: I think you need to get rid of the anchors.  You want to match the start or end of the string **or** between a digit and a pipe.  The word boundaries handle both conditions.

Comment: I tried to run this, both with and without the anchors, and it causes the following error in impala: 

Your query has the following error(s):

    Bad status for request 6360:      TGetOperationStatusResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=None, errorMessage=None, sqlState=None, infoMessages=None, statusCode=0), operationState=5, errorMessage=None, sqlState=None, errorCode=None)